# Closing a specific IE browser with process ID

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently developing a tool that will run automation test cases.
So at the moment, I wanted to make the test cases run concurrently by creating a new thread for each of the test case.

```
Thread playThread = new Thread(this.PlayMainConcurrent);
playThread.Start(main);
```

When the playThread is started, an IE browser will launch and perform the automation, and there will be a few IE browser launched together. I want to know is there any way to close a specific IE browser among the browser launched by process id?

What I have tried is using

```
playThread.Abort();
```

but this only exited the thread, not closing the browser.

Also, I have tried using Process.Kill()

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"))
{
      proc.Kill();
}
```

this did closes the ie browser, however i don't want it to close all my ie browser because i just one to kill only one specific browser.

Additionally, my project can only support .NET Framework 2.0 and are not able to update to newer one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you start IE, do you use something like `var process = Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "http://google.com");`? In that case, you have the process there, just call `process.Kill();` on it.

Comment: @kaffekopp i didn't use it because the IE is launched using library of the automation, therefore I could not get the process unless I get it by process name iexplore

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to keep the reference of each process

```
// Start a procecss that opens a Notepad
Process myProcess = Process.Start("Notepad.exe")
// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
// Free resources associated with process.
myProcess.Close();
```

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=netframework-2.0)

Comment: Though a good answer, OP posted _"IE is launched using library of the automation, therefore I could not get the process unless I get it by process name iexplore"_ a couple of minutes after your post